# Specific network has issues (16.04 LTS)

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, connection, wicd

I'm pulling my hair out trying to get my network working properly. I've tested it through a USB hotspot and a normal Wi-Fi hotspot, and it works perfectly. But whenever I connect to my home network, the ping always gets progressively higher for about two minutes until the internet access (not the connection to the router) drops out all together, and refuses to come back for another five minutes, even after reconnecting.

It's doubtful that the signal strength is a problem, because every other device I have can connect to it, and WICD (yes, I had the same problem with Network Manager) is placing the signal strength at 97%. Plus, I used to be able to connect on this system when it had Windows 10, and also on Ubuntu in a previous Dual-Boot between Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 12.10.

My Wi-Fi card is the RTL8188EE. I thought at first that the card was the problem, but absolutely nothing changed after trying every solution I could find.

The site told me to add the info I get from running the commands at [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into/61547#61547), so here's that (commands run while connected to a wireless hotspot):

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: 34:23:87:57:9a:51
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=4.4.0-43-generic firmware=N/A ip=172.20.10.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:33 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0200000-f0203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 07
       serial: a0:d3:c1:5a:cf:47
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:31 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff memory:f0010000-f001ffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@5:2
       logical name: enp0s16f0u2c4i2
       serial: ea:80:2e:cf:b9:85
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipheth link=no multicast=yes

02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```